# referenceerror when adding inline jquery in haml

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am trying to put some inline javascript inside .haml in rails but I am getting an uncaught reference error: `$ is not defined
    at $('#expl').hover(function() {`

There might be an obvious solution but I can't see it. This is the code:

```
    %label.form-group__data{ for: bla bla bla }
      = t('.search_in_db')
      .box{:id=>"expl"}

  :javascript
     $('#expl').hover(function() {
      $(t('.search_in_db_expl')).show();
      },
      function() {
      $(t('.search_in_db_expl')).hide();
      });
```

I am trying to add this as a hover text

Comment: It looks like you are using jQuery. What version of Rails are you using? If you are using Rails >=5.1, you'll have to install the jquery-rails gem.

Comment: @hashrocket yes indeed it's jQuery and I'm using rails 5.0.0.1

Comment: Make sure your jQuery library is getting loaded before your javascript is run.

Comment: @hashrocket okay, you were right the jQuery library wasn't loaded, so I fixed this `referenceError` but I still don't have the needed solution. It doesn't do show anything when I hover over the text.

Comment: Did you restart your server?

Comment: @hashrocket yes, there was a problem I didn't put the id in the label, so I fixed it now. Thanks anyhow for your answers.